# Probability for sparse matrix after permutation

Tags: probability

I need to calculate the probability of the following question, it is kind of tricky but I cannot work out the exact value.

For a sparse (most of its entries are zero) matrix $X=[x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_N]$ of size $N\times N$, count the number of nonzero elements of each column of $X$ and denote the result as $S=[s_1, s_2,\cdots, s_N]$. **They satisfy the condition that $s_1\ge s_2\ge \cdots \ge s_N \ge  0$.** Get the column which have the most number of nonzero entries by $||S||_{\infty} = max_{j} ~{s_j}$.

Shuffle (permute) the locations of the matrix $X$ randomly and denote the result as $X^*=[x^*_1, x^*_2, \cdots, x^*_N]$. Once again, count the number of nonzero elements of each column of $X^*$ and denote the result as $S^*=[s^*_1,s^*_2, \cdots, s^*_N]$. Then we have $||S^*||_{\infty}= max_{j}~ {s^*_j}$.

**I want the compute the probability (or the lower bound) $Prob(||S^*||_{\infty} <  ||S||_{\infty})$.**

I try to solve the problem as follows:

The mean of $S$ is $\hat{s}=\sum_{j} s_j/N$ and after permutation, every $s^*_j$ will not deviate this value very far. I try to model the permutation process as  flipping a coin $N^2$ times, then each entry of $X^*$ will have a nonzero value with probability $p=\hat{s}/N$ (the coin is head) and be $0$ with probability $1-p$ (the coin is tail). Then
\begin{eqnarray}
Prob(||S^*||_{\infty} <  ||S||_{\infty})=& 1-Prob(||S^*||_{\infty} \ge  ||S||_{\infty})
\\=& 1-Prob(||S^*||_{\infty} \ge  ||S||_{\infty}>\hat{s})
\\>& 1-Prob(||S^*||_{\infty} >\hat{s})
\\=& 0.
\end{eqnarray}
The last equation comes from the definition of $||S^*||_{\infty}$.

Intuitively, this probability will be very large, but the lower bound I got is far from what I want.

Comment: Intuitively, this probability should highly depend on $S$, since we are somewhat observing subtracting $1$ from a $s_i$ and adding $1$ to a (possibly the same) $s_j$. For $S = (s,s,s,s,s,\ldots)$ I expect that $P = 0$ whereas for $S = (\| S \|_\infty, 0, 0, 0, 0, \ldots)$ I expect $P \approx 1$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I put more constraints on $S$, would you please have a look?

Comment: The new constraint is more of a WLOG unless you require the same for $S^\ast$ as well...